# UWP LogicalTreeViewHelper

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime, dependencyobject

I'm trying to convert an library from wpf to uwp.
I'm almost done but now there is the LogicalTreeViewHelper which doesn't exist in UWP anymore.

does anyone know how to replace it in uwp?

```
var parent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(MyDependencyObject);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In UWP, you should use the [VisualTreeHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper) class instead.

There are quite a few toolkits and helpers around to do this, I personally have my [Cimbalino Toolkit](https://cimbalino.org) which provides direct extension methods so you could just do:

```
var parent = MyDependencyObject.GetVisualParent();
```

For this to work, you can either go the simple route add the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cimbalino.Toolkit) to your solution or just take the bits you need from the [source code](https://github.com/Cimbalino/Cimbalino-Toolkit/blob/master/src/Cimbalino.Toolkit.Core%20(WP8)/Extensions/DependencyObjectExtensions.cs)

Comment: thanks. I took a look inside the github Project and all what this function does is returning VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject); So in my case I dont Need this Extension-method.

Comment: the .Parent property on FrameworkElement should give you the LogicalParent rather than the VisualParent, if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the UWP Toolkit to get some handy extensions for traversing the Visual Tree (**Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI** nuget package)

https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit